# Why does SSIS prefix the files uploaded to FTP with an underscore?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ftp, ssis

I'm transferring a file to remote FTP server using FTP task. After the file is transferred to FTP server, I see **`_`** (*underscore*) prefix added to file automatically.

When *FileName.Zip* is uploaded to an FTP website , on FTP server I see the file name as *`_FileName.zip`*. A

The FTP task within SSIS is generating the file name using local variable. the variable has the *`Evaluate as Expression`* property set to true and uses the below expression. There are no underscores in the expression.

#### Expression used in the variable:

```
@[User::InputPath]+ "\\" +@[User::ZIPFile]
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: @Siva No, expression is not adding _ prefix. Here is the expression @[User::InputPath]+"\\" +@[User::ZIPFile]

Comment: @Siva That is not helpful. OP of the that question wrote a script to remove the _ prefix on FTP server after file is transferred :)

Comment: Siva has made a good suggestion - Rule that particular issue out beforehand before you pursue other solutions. It's always a good idea to unit test different pieces to rule out particular scenarios.

Comment: Can we see the expression formula for this variable?